# Select, Join left, Union. Help me,

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables flowing and i try to build a query to show the results. But it just show exactly half.

```
Project
--------------
id    name
--------------
1     Project 1
2     Project 2
3     Project 3
4     Project 4
5     Project 5
6     Project 6


Pj_rp
-----------------------------
id    id_pj          id_rp
-----------------------------
1     1               1
2     2               2
3     1               3
4     2               4
5     1               5
6     3               6

Report
--------------
id    Fee
--------------
1     200
2     200
3     400
4     400
5     400
6     400
```

I want to get results

```
**result**
--------------------
Project      SUM(Fee)
--------------------
Project 1     1000
Project 2      600
Project 3      400
Project 4     NULL
Project 5     NULL
Project 6     NULL
```

And i built the folowing query but it wrong

```
SELECT 
    a.name, c.Fee
from
    Project a
        LEFT JOIN
    Pj_rp b ON (a.id = b.id_pj)
        LEFT JOIN
    Report c ON (b.id_rp = c.id)
GROUP BY a.tongmucdautuduan_usd
```

I have no idea, who can help me to solve this?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you forget to "SUM(c.Fee)" in your query?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    a.name "Project", sum(c.Fee)
from
    Project a
        LEFT JOIN
    Pj_rp b ON (a.id = b.id_pj)
        LEFT JOIN
    Report c ON (b.id_rp = c.id)
GROUP BY a.name
```